# PHP password hashing with password_compat library

Tags: php, password-encryption

I have a tiny question about using the [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) library. I've only just updated my local PHP version to 5.4.x to be able to use this library.

Now it says on the page that you need to check the value `password_hash` make, since it could be `false`:

> It is very important that you should check the return value of
>   password_hash prior to storing it, because a false may be returned if
>   it encountered an error.

Now how do I do this? Would the following code work:

```
$password = password_hash($_POST['pass'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
if($password){
    //succes!
}else{
    //error
}
```

I'm just a little confused since it's not always a boolean that gets returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function will return a truthy value if it has succeeded, so the code you have shown will work.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php